# Symbol Not Found in AsynchronousSocketChannel Reas/Connection Handler

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop TCP/IP communication application in Android using Java via AsynchronousSocketChannel. I am getting symbol not found error for my private data members in my read handler.
I have no prior experience in Android App development or in Java but I worked extensively in C++.
The program is based on template from by C++ Boost.Asio application which is working properly.
OS - Windows 10 64-bit
Target Platform - Android Things Raspberry Pi 1.08

```
public class Ethernet {
    private String                      ip;
    private int                         portNo;
    private Queue<String>               recvQueue, sendQueue;
    private InetAddress                 address;
    private String                      readData;
    private InputStream                 in;
    private OutputStream                out;
    private AsynchronousSocketChannel   socket;
    private boolean                     socketAlive, connectionInProgress;
    private ByteBuffer                  readBuffer;

    Ethernet(String ip, int port) {
        if (port > 65535 && port < 1024)
            port = 6666;
        this.ip = ip;
        this.portNo = port;
        this.socketAlive = false;
        this.connectionInProgress = false;
        this.readBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
    }

    private void recieveDataSocket(){
        this.socket.read(this.readBuffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                if (result < 0) {
                    this.socketAlive = false;  //Error
                }
                else if (this.readBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
                    // repeat the call with the same CompletionHandler
                    this.socket.read(this.readBuffer, null, this);//Error
                }
                else {
                    // got all data, process the buffer
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable e, Object attachment) {
                // handle the failure
            }
        });
    } }
```

> Error :

```
error: cannot find symbol
this.socketAlive = false;
^  symbol: variable socketAlive  error: cannot find symbol
else if (this.readBuffer.remaining() > 0) {
^  symbol: variable readBuffer  error: cannot find symbol
this.socket.read(this.readBuffer, null, this);
^   symbol: variable readBuffer   error: cannot find symbol
this.socket.read(this.readBuffer, null, this);
 ^   symbol: variable socket   error: cannot find symbol
eth.disconnect();
^   symbol:   method disconnect()   location: variable eth of type Ethernet 5 errors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point of the error `this` is referring to the anonymous class you created with `new CompletionHandler ...` and this class does not have a member `socketAlive`.

To fix that, just leave out the `this.`.